# how to move checkbox end of node label in treePanel in extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs4.1, treepanel

By default check box comes left side of label on node in treePanel in extjs 4.1.
But i want to move check box left to right of label on node.

Answer (score 0):

Just apply `float: right;` to the tree checkbox class. Check the fiddle -

http://jsfiddle.net/vdazU/3238/